# ffmpeg - Access elements of AVCodecContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, 64-bit, avcodec

I want to access some members of my `AVCodecContext *av_ctx` in my program. It is fine when I compile it in 32bit version, But when I change it to 64bit this elements act like they been shifted.

**For example**, I want to get `av_ctx->coded_width` and `av_ctx->coded_height` (sometimes they are different from `av_ctx->width` and `av_ctx->height`) and store them in some variables. Now when I debug this program in 32bit version it's Ok, but in 64bit version this values are wrong and when I check my structure I can see the next two elements (`av_ctx->gop_size` and `av_ctx->pix_fmt`) has the values that I want.

I checked `AVCodecContext` declaration on `avcodec.h` and it (in comments above structure declaration) says:

> Please use AVOptions (av_opt* / av_set/get*()) to access these fields from user applications.

I think this might be the right way to get these elements but I don't know what is this **AVOptions**, I searched it but couldn't find what is it exactly and how can I use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int64_t cheight = 0; 
av_opt_set_int(av_ctx,"coded_height", 400, 0); 
av_opt_get_int(av_ctx,"coded_height", 0, &cheight);
```

maybe you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tested it and `av_opt_get_int` returns -1 on this elements. I can get some elements of `AVCodecContext` with this method but not this one.